# SharePoint2013 REST: Get user profile properties

Tags: user-profile-service, rest, user

I've been fighting to get user data using the REST API but I can't get it to work mainly because I am getting a server error 500

```
"Network Error: 500 Internet Server Error - http://mysite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong but I can't get over this error at all. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this or how I can fix this.  Here is my REST code as well

```
//Connection and Data
function getMyUserProfile(success, error) {
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        success(data.d);
    },
    error: error
});
}

// Usage   
getMyUserProfile(
           function (properties) {
          document.getElementById("sp-name").innerHTML = (properties.DisplayName),
          document.getElementById("sp-avatar").innerHTML = (properties.PictureUrl);
      },
      function (data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
```

Comment: Does the returned URL actually contain some data? Have you tried defining siteUrl variable as `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;`?

Comment: Where is this code situated? In a SharePoint page in an app? Make sure an app has the correct permissions.

Comment: Hi there, this code is actually in the masterpage as I need this to cross the entire site so I can display a username in the header of said master page.

Comment: When I define it as

    _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

I get the same error

Comment: Your code worked successfully on my site.  Can I assume you are on prem?  Is this  your first attempt at REST in this environment, or have you successfully used REST in this environment before?

Comment: This is my first attempt at using REST. My site is a publishing site and I my REST file in my JS folder and the master pages references it.

Comment: Is this on prem or SharePoint Online?

Comment: wjervis this is prem mate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a little messing I managed to get this to work. Despite having a publishing site I still had to set up my site and also the active directory connection and synchronisation service.  With those items in place the Internal Server error 500 vanished and the data was displayed.

Thanks to everyone for their help in getting to the bottom of this, a simple fix but without knowing it's hard to pin point immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow there is an issue reading all of the properties of an account so try to select only what you want like in the url

```
siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=AccountNamr,Email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below URL :

> _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+ "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

If you still do not get the code working try accessing the URL in the browser

> http://yoursite.yourdomain.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

and see if the results are returned. If you get a feed reading error in the IE, you can go to the IE options -> Content tab -> Feeds section "setting" -> Uncheck the "Turn on feed reading view"

Comment: If I try to access the url in a browser I get the following error. 

   <m:error><m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Unknown Error</m:message></m:error>
Not helpful I know but that's what I get

Comment: Have you referenced the SP.UserProfiles.js ?

Comment: I thought I had.  Can you do me a favor and show me where and how I would do that? It would help a lot in working through this problem.

Comment: You can use the SharePoint:Scriptlink tag to include the JS in your master page. Refer this: [link](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/30/how-to-properly-reference-sp-js-in-a-master-page/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have added SP.UserProfiles.js as suggested but the error remains the same. This is so frustrating. I'm not sure what else it could be...any ideas?

Comment: Can you find your profile in the User profile service application ? You are facing this issue [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105922/sharepoint-user-profile-rest-api-unknown-error) Have a look and check if it works..Not sure why a mysite has to be created. Having a user profile should work !

Comment: My site is a publishing site does that make a difference?